# How to hide navigation bar permanently

Tags: android

How to hide navigation bar permanently if I long click the button the app is closed otherwise the application is in full view mode without navigation bar hide top to bottom swipe also

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html#SystemUI

(Controls for system UI visibility section) :

> **The SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION** is a new flag that requests the navigation bar hide completely. Be aware that this works only for the navigation bar used by some handsets **(it does not hide the system bar on tablets).**

However, you could try to dim the system bar as done sometimes during gaming and video playback.

> The **SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE** flag replaces the STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN flag. When set, this flag enables “low profile" mode for the system bar or navigation bar. Navigation buttons dim and other elements in the system bar also hide. Enabling this is useful for creating more immersive games without distraction for the system navigation buttons.

**Plz try this way**

**There are two ways to hide the navigation bar:**

**Way 1:**

Touch “Settings” -> “Display” -> “Navigation bar” -> “Buttons” -> “Button layout”. Choose the pattern in “Hide navigation bar” -> When the app opens, the navigation bar will be automatically hidden and you can swipe up from the bottom corner of the screen to show it.

**Way 2:**

Touch “Settings” -> “Display” -> “Navigation bar” -> “Fullscreen gestures”. The navigation bar will be hidden and you will be shown “Gesture demos” to explain how to operate the “Go back”, “Go to Home screen” and “Open Recents” functions.

**OR**

**Programetically**

**Step 1** − Create a new project in Android Studio, go to File ⇒ New Project and fill all required details to create a new project.

**Step 2** − Add the following code to res/layout/activity_main.xml.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">
       <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Step 3** − Add the following code to src/MainActivity.java

```
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private int currentApiVersion;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
  final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
     View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
     View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
     View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
  if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
     getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
     final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
     decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new 
     View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
           if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
              decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
           }
          }
       });
     }
  }
  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  @Override
  public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && hasFocus) {
     
   getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
      }
   }
}
```

**Step 4** − Add the following code to androidManifest.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
           package="app.com.sample">
            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
          <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
          </activity>
         </application>
    </manifest>
```

[image]